# Sencha Touch: programmatically change toggle value with animation

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

An `Ext.field.Toggle` status can be changed programmatically using the `.toggle()` or `.setValue()` methods. This however doesn't trigger the animation on the component like it was actually dragged or tapped. Is there a way to obtain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by firing `tap` on the underlying element of the `Ext.slider.Toggle` contained in the `Ext.field.Toggle`:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.CustomToggle', {
    extend: 'Ext.field.Toggle',
    xtype : 'customtogglefield',

    toggle: function() {
        this.getComponent().element.fireEvent('tap');
    }

});
```

Example at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/669